# Volume of a Solid Bounded by the $xy$ plane and a function

Tags: calculus

The question reads to evaluate the volume of the solid bounded by the function

$f(x,y)=(y\sin(\pi x))^2$ and the $xy$-plane.

I know that this is a double integral problem, where we are integrating over $f(x,y)$. However what are my boundardy points.

I tried setting $f(x,y)=0$ because we can treat $z=f(x,y)$ and since the function is bounded on the $xy$-plane then $z=0$.

But i get $y=0$ and $x=n$, where $n$ is an integer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plot of $z = f(x, y)$ on $[-2, 2] \times [-2, 2]$.  You are correct that $f(x, y) = 0$ exactly for $(x, y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$.  The integral is certainly unbounded.

[image]